# Formatting ASPX files in VS2008 and editor line width

Tags: visual-studio-2008, asp.net

This isn't a programming question per say, but very programming related, so I figured I'd ask here instead of superuser.com

We invested in some nice widescreen monitors at work so we all have nice 1920x1200 resolution and a wide visual studio window when it is maximized. The problem is when we hit ctrl-k-d to autoformat the aspx code, it seems to default to a line length for a 4:3 monitor. Is there a way to overwrite this setting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, there's an option

Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> HTML -> Format -> Length

Regards,
Will